# ¿Cómo utilizar un binario desensamblado para encontrar el límite de desbordamiento de búfer?

Tags: c, overflow

Estoy intentando utilizar el binario proporcionado para leer el archivo bingo.txt en el servidor remoto. Por eso utilicé ghidra para desmontarlo y me encontré con la función `main`:

```
undefined8 main(void)

{
  undefined local_38 [44];
  __uid_t local_c;
  
  local_c = geteuid();
  printf("username: ");
  fflush(stdout);
  __isoc99_scanf(&DAT_0010200f,local_38);
  if (local_c == 0) {
    system("cat bingo.txt");
  }
  else {
    system("cat bongo.txt");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

No pude ejecutar el archivo a pesar de mi `chmod +x` pero intenté eso: al principio pensé que podría escribir 0 para ir a `local_c`, pero no funcionó. Luego pensé que como la memoria era 44 podría escribir 45 0's y entonces el último 0 se tomaría en local_c pero tampoco funcionó. Así que probé a aumentar los 0's uno a uno y descubrí que a partir de 315 0's el servidor ya no respondía

Comment: Aquí tienes un buen video al respecto, aunque sin hidra https://youtu.be/qpyRz5lkRjE